# how to calculate the max elements accessed using binary search and a sorted list?

Tags: algorithm

148 elements which has a log base 2 of 7.2 ?

So I have to round up to calculate max elements accessed or round down ?

8 or 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikipedia says: ⌊log2(N)+1⌋ , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Performance

Comment: Actually, `floor(log2(n)+1)` is not the same as `ceil(log2(n))`. Just consider the case `n = 2`: one is `floor(1+1) = 2`, the other is `ceil(1) = 1`.